# How to convert apollo client fetchMore updateQuery to apollo cache merge function?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am learning apollo and graphQL and have a simple application that displays a list of data, with a fetchMore function that adds to the array.

I would like to remove the updateQuery as it is being deprecated and use the new field policy merge function. The current cache setup and updateQuery looks like this:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    client_client: {
      fields: {
        // add local only value to clients
        isEdited: {
          read(value = false) {
            // when writing the new value return new value or false as default
            return value;
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
  const onFetchMore = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        offset: page
      },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult, queryVariables }) => {
        return {
          ...previousResult,
          client_client: [
            ...previousResult.client_client,
            ...fetchMoreResult.client_client,
          ],
        };
      },
    });
  }
```

However I cannot seem to get it to work as a merge function within the cache for apollo client v3. I have tried adding the merge in many different places however it always seems to break the application.

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, define field policy within the `typePolicies` option provided in the `InMemoryCache` constructor:

> ```
> const cache = new InMemoryCache({   typePolicies: {
>     Query: {
>       fields: {
>         feed: {
>           // Don't cache separate results based on
>           // any of this field's arguments.
>           keyArgs: false,
>           // Concatenate the incoming list items with
>           // the existing list items.
>           merge(existing = [], incoming) {
>             return [...existing, ...incoming];
>           },
>         }
>       }
>     }   } })
> ```

Then you just pass the `offset` and `limit` to the initial query:

> ```
> const { loading, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_ITEMS, {
>   variables: {
>     offset: 0,
>     limit: 10
>   },
> });
> ```

and `fetchMore` to get the next iteration:

> ```
> fetchMore({
>   variables: {
>     offset: 10,
>     limit: 10
>   },
> });
> ```

Checkout the docs here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/

Comment: where do you get the value of fields: 'feed' ?

Comment: @Steve the fields is a map that specifies the modifier function to call for each modified field. So "feed" here is a query field returned by graphql query, i.e 

`...
query Feed($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    feed(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
...
`